# How is for...of used in other languages which made it relevant for ECMAScript-6?

Tags: ecmascript-6, methodology, syntactic-sugar, convenience-methods, for-of-loop

I noticed [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loops were added to the ECMAScript-6 proposal, but have never heard of them until now. What's the typical use case for them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use case is when you want to do something with each element of an array.  `for...in` in ECMAScript will sort of let you go over the array *indices* (and even that incorrectly).

The Python equivalent of ES6 `for...of` is `for...in`, like so:

```
myList = [ "a", "b", 5]
for el in myList:
  # el takes on the values "a", "b", 5 in that order
  pass
```

Comment: Some languages call this `foreach`... in fact ES5 calls it `forEach` when used as a method on an array, but the `for...of` syntax cuts out a lot of the extra weight and allows it to easily be used on non-arrays.